# Cronjob for a bash script pauses for 2 minutes once in a while

Tags: bash, cron, lockfile

I am trying to run a bash script on CEntOS 5.5 machine that checks replication on a remote mysql server. The script creates a temporary lock file and is scheduled to run in Crontab every minute. But once in a while the cron job goes out of sync - pauses or delays the jobs for two minutes and tries to run three jobs at a time. This is creating false alarms, flooding my mailbox saying that "Lock file exists! Possible conflict".

Here is the part of the script that might be of interest:

```
#!/bin/sh

lock_file=/tmp/slave_alert.lck
finished=0

# Alert function
function mail_alert () {
        cat /var/log/replication_check.log | mail -s "Replication check errors!" mail@mail.com
}    

# Check if lock file exists
if [ -f $lock_file ];
then
        echo "Lock file exists! Possible conflict!" > /var/log/replication_check.log 2>&1
        mail_alert
        exit 1
else
        touch $lock_file
fi

finished=1


while [ $finished -ne 0 ]
do

if [Replication is not configured or you do not have the required access to MySQL];
then
        rm $lock_file
        exit 1
fi
# Do some logic
sleep 1
done

rm $lock_file

echo "Script complete!"
exit 0
```

Here is the Cronjob:

```
* 0-1,4-23 * * * path/check_replication.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Here is a part of the output of the log file: /var/log/cron . We can see that 14:35 and 14:36 are delayed.

Let us name this string CRONJOB = (root) CMD (path/check_replication.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)

```
Sep 23 14:30:01 remote-host crond[3959]: CRONJOB
Sep 23 14:31:01 remote-host crond[4025]: CRONJOB
Sep 23 14:32:01 remote-host crond[4054]: CRONJOB
Sep 23 14:33:01 remote-host crond[4102]: CRONJOB
Sep 23 14:34:01 remote-host crond[4129]: CRONJOB
Sep 23 14:37:00 remote-host crond[4276]: CRONJOB
Sep 23 14:37:01 remote-host crond[4308]: CRONJOB
Sep 23 14:37:02 remote-host crond[4365]: CRONJOB
Sep 23 14:38:01 remote-host crond[4129]: CRONJOB
Sep 23 14:39:01 remote-host crond[4129]: CRONJOB
```

Comment: Well, they are not really skipped, just executed later than expected, aren't they?

Comment: It might be better to run mail_alert only if the lockfile is older than X minutes.